# ImageMagick convert command produces a slight error

Tags: terminal, command-line, graphics

This happens when I convert a GIF into a series of PNG files.

I convert a .gif animation to a series of .png using

```
convert ex.gif my_png_files_%d.png
```

I get a series of .png-figures but some of the figures seem to be slightly shifted to the side or up/down. Example: if the gif-animation was just a red circle centred in the middle of a square, then the series of the pngs would produce this circle but this circle would be slight shifted off center in some direction in some of the pngs.

Anyone know what the issue is here?

Answer (score 1):

First, shouldn't your example be :

```
convert ex.gif my_png_files_%d.png
```

as the input file is the GIF?

Could this be an anti-aliasing problem? Have you tried

```
convert ex.gif +antialiasing my_png_files_%d.png
```

I assume you have read [the manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) or the local copy at file:///opt/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.8.0/www/convert.html

**EDIT:** It turned out to be a geometry problem and the answer found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791505/how-to-extract-frames-from-a-gif-file-preserving-frame-dimensions was to change the command to

```
convert -coalesce ex.gif +antialiasing my_png_files_%d.png
```

Comment: You're right on the first point, it was a misprint, sorry.

Comment: On the second point, it gives the error: convert: UnrecognizedOption `+antialiasing' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/720.

Comment: Always best to use copy and paste :)

Comment: The +antialiasing didn't work, it produces an error.

Comment: It seems that the individual PNGs are of different sizes when they should all have identical sizes. Do you have any idea where this size difference comes from?

Comment: OK, looks like it's not an anti-aliasing problem. I'd try turning off the PNG adaptive filtering as well. Look at the `quality` option. As for the differing geometry on output I'd also look at explicitly setting the output geometry.

Comment: Yes I think the geometry output could fix the problem, the only thing is that I don't know how to write that line :(

Comment: Yes, ImageMagick is always fun. I've "wasted" hours on getting a command line right. You will need to find a way of extracting the right geometry from the original GIF and passing it to the command. It is usually at this point I start thinking about a small Python script :)

Comment: Try asking your question in the [support forums for ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/index.php)

Comment: Haha OK so I wrote convert EXAMPLE.gif -resize 500x500 my_%d.png but the problem now is that the figures are still of different size :(

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791505/how-to-extract-frames-from-a-gif-file-preserving-frame-dimensions

Comment: Perfect, you're the man!